# Изменить верстку с position: sticky на что то лучше

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

На сайте [info.nadv.ru](http://info.nadv.ru/) есть прокручивающийся блок с position: sticky. Блок скролится под блоком с карточками (capabilities-container). Этот блок с карточками (Начинается от заголовка "Возможности") имеет position: absolute.

Проблема в том, что если количество карточек в абсолютном блоке меняется тоже, то высота блока меняется, а высота блока (capabilities-list), в котором скролится карта  (capabilites-map) - нет.

Количество карточек в абсолютном блоке меняется в зависимости от положения бегунка "для жителей" "для бизнеса" (и срединная позиция еще, код  есть в теле страницы).

Соответственно, если карточек мало, то появляется баг - слишком большой по высоте контейнер (capabilities-list {min-height: 4360px;}), высота которого не меняется никак, кроме как в ручную.

Нужно как-то переделать верстку, чтобы сохранить функционал скролящейся под блоком карты и в целом, оставить все на месте, но избавиться от position: absolute, чтобы высота блока .capabilities-list менялась в зависимости от кол-ва карточек в блоке "Возможности"? (capabilities-container).

Как это можно сделать? В проекте уже есть Jquery и Bootstrap, так что если есть решение с применением данных инструментов, то хорошо.

P.S или может как то JavaScript'ом менять высоту блока в зависимости от количества карточек в "Возможности"...

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_affix.asp

Comment: @soledar10 подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу (если могу) этому элементу data-spy указать высоту блока с карточками?